# Cross domain postMessage, identify iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain, xss

I use `postMessage` to send events from an iframe to it's parent document. I have control over both sides but the content comes from two different domains.

[image]

My simple problem is, that i can not identify the iFrame inside of it's parent callback method. The implementation looks like this:

**In the iFrame:**

```
parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify({action: "closeView" }),'*');
```

**In the parent window:**

```
window.addEventListener('message',function(event) {
if(event.origin !== 'https://example.com')
    return;

    // Parse message back to json
    var messageObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
    var source = event.source;
    /* this is returning: Window -URL- */
    console.log( source );
    /* This will throw Permission denied, although this code is inside of "parent" */
    console.log(source.parentNode);
},false);
```

I want to identify a certain parent element of the iframe, which is (logically) inside of the parent document.

When i try to use `event.source.parentNode` or some jQuery on said object, Firefox says, i can not do this to prevent XSS, error: `Error: Permission denied to access property 'parentNode'`

How can i get the parent element of the iFrame, that triggered the `postMessage` event listener?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you can use window names for this, as they pass from iframe tag to iframe context.

parent doc:

```
<iframe name=fr2 src="data:text/html,%3Chtml%3E%0A%20%3Cscript%3E%20parent.postMessage%28%7Bname%3A%20window.name%7D%2C%20%22*%22%29%3B%3C/script%3E%0A%3C/html%3E"></iframe>
<iframe name=fr3 src="data:text/html,%3Chtml%3E%0A%20%3Cscript%3E%20parent.postMessage%28%7Bname%3A%20name%7D%2C%20%22*%22%29%3B%3C/script%3E%0A%3C/html%3E"></iframe>

<script>onmessage = function(e){ // use real event handlers in production
       alert("from frame: " + e.data.name);
 };</script>
```

iframe doc:

```
<html>
 <script> parent.postMessage({name: name}, "*");</script>
</html>
```

which alerts "fr2", then "fr3".
you can then easily use the *name* attrib to find the iframe in the parent DOM using attrib CSS selectors.

illustrative demo of window.name+iframe concept: http://pagedemos.com/namingframes/

this painfully simple approach is also immune to issues arising from same-url iframes.

Comment: You are right, thank you very much. just obtain `window.name` inside of the `<iframe>` does return the name like expected. Like stated in my answer from last year i tried to get the `id` or `name` inside of the `eventListener`, which still does not work. Anyways, it seems to be the best idea to just use the `name` attribute and send it with the `postMessage` like you did. This is clearly better than relying on the url. I will check this as answer when the bounty of @Călin Darie is due. Maybe this user also wants to make an addition. Thanks again.

Comment: This is such a straightforward approach. You could even autogenerate the names on the server with a unique key - so you wouldn't even have to worry about cross-window/tab pollution.

Answer (score 5):

As per my understanding this may be try
here suppose your main window's url is www.abc.com\home.php

```
  <body>
         <iframe src="www.abc.com\getOtherDomainContent.php?otherUrl=www.xyz.com"/>
    </body>
```

getOtherDomainContent.php in this file need to write ajax call which get cross url content and push that content in current iframe window(getOtherDomainContent.php)'s body part.

getOtherDomainContent.php
Code:

```
    <html>
         <head>
//import jqry lib or other you use.
          <script>
              $(document).ready({
               //getcontent of xyz.com
                var otherUrlContent=getAjaxHtml("www.xyz.com");
                 $("body").html(otherUrlContent);
                  // further  code after content pushed.
                  //you can easily access "parent.document" and else using parent which will give you all thing you want to do with your main window
                });
          </script>
         </head>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but this answer is not really addressing the actual question. Why should I load the remote content by ajax in the first place? I could just set the `<iframe src="http://www.example.com">` to get the content to be displayed. To answer the question it is mandatory to use `postMessage`. The problem is not to get a page to be displayed, but to listen on an event from the `<iframe>` and identify the `<iframe>` that triggered the event in the parent document. Cheers.

Comment: Little addition: I do understand where you wanted to go with the ajax approach. But even if this should work (i guess not without having a lot of trouble with `CORS`), the content of the `<iframe>` will be written over as soon as you navigate inside of the `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 4):

Like seen in this thread: [postMessage Source IFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329710/postmessage-source-iframe/20404180#20404180) it is possible to compare each iframes `contentWindow` with `event.source` like this:

```
/*each(iframe...){ */
frames[i].contentWindow === event.source
```

But i did not like this too much. My solution for now looks like this:

**In the iFrame:**

```
parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify({action: "closeView", viewUrl: document.URL}),'*');
```

**Update:**
`docuent.URL` can become a problem, when you use queries or links with location (#anchor) since your current url will become different from the one of the iframe source. So Instead of `document.URL` it's better to use `[location.protocol, '//', location.host, location.pathname].join('')` ([Is there any method to get the URL without query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817505/is-there-any-method-to-get-url-without-query-string-in-java-script/5817566#5817566))

**In the parent document:**

```
window.addEventListener('message',function(event) {

    if(event.origin !== 'https://example.com')
        return;

    // Parse message back to json
    var messageObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
    // Get event triggering iFrame
    var triggerFrame = $('iframe[src="'+messageObject.viewUrl+'"]');

 },false);
```

Each event will have to send the current iFrame URL to the parent document. We now can scan our documents for the iFrame with the given URL and work with it.

If some of you know a better way please post your answers.