# window.postMessage to open window/tab

Tags: javascript, postmessage

I can't seem to find an answer to this one; but have open windows/tabs and i'm trying to communicate between them with the postMessage and eventListener...nothing seems to be working. Each window/tab has a name to it; how do i reference that window/tab by it's name? Tried every solution I'm seeing but nothing is working. window.open() trick doesn't work either as it's blocked by default or just isn't working.

```
const myWindow = window.open('', 'myName');
```

results in a null myWindow so postMessage can't do anything, tried sending a url too with the same null result.

```
myWindow.postMessage({'e': 123, 'f': 456, 'g': 789}, '*');
```

using * just for SNG to test. Various posts allude to this being able to work but no example has been successful so far and no reference on how to target the already open window/tab by it's name. There are also several domains that could possibly be used by the company (CORS enabled) and opened at the same time in different tabs.

Comment: you have to open or frame a window to get a handle to use with postMessage. You can use `storage` events to send info between different windows on the same domain, regardless of how they were opened. If you have many domains, you can use a server relay package like firebase, or have them all embed a hidden iframe from one domain where you use postMessage or storage events to talk to the iframe, which can then postMessage to `top`.

Comment: so no way to target a window by name? ok, i thought maybe using service workers too but that can't do the cross-domain thing. I'll probably have to use an iframe trigger with localstorage then for the different domains. Thank you :)

Comment: there's also webrtc data channels and shared workers, but i reckon that storage events, though a bit convoluted in practice with it's hidden frames and all that, is still the simplest client-only solution. If your need is simple/1-time, you might also consider the "name transport", https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629421/cross-domain-postmessage-identify-iframe/30359348#30359348