# How JavaScript objects passed with postMessage

Tags: javascript, html, messaging, postmessage

I have been playing with `HTML` `postMessage` and managed to pass messages between my web page and the popup window it opens.

index.html:

```
var popup;
window.onload = function () {
    console.log("window.onload");
    var btn = document.getElementById('signin');
    btn.addEventListener('click', signin);
};

var pollTimer;

function signin(e) {
    console.log("window.onload - signin");
    popup = window.open("http://www.olcayertas.com/testqa/redirect.html", "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=10, left=700, width=600, height=600");

    pollTimer = window.setInterval(function () {

        if (popup.closed !== false) { // !== is required for compatibility with Opera
            window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
            document.getElementById('signin').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }

        e.preventDefault();
        popup.postMessage('message', 'http://www.olcayertas.com/testqa/index.html');
        console.log("sendMessage - Message sent!!!");

    }, 500);
}

function receiveMessage(event){
    window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
}

window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

popup.html:

```
console.log("script");
window.onload = first();
var messageEle;

function receiveMessage(e) {
    console.log("receiveMessage");
    messageEle = document.getElementById('message');
    messageEle.innerHTML = "Message Received: " + e.data;
    e.source.postMessage("Mesaj alındı!", e.origin);
}

function first() {
    console.log("first");
    window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage);
}
```

What I need is redirect the user to an other page by setting `top.location` parameter in my popup window and pass the `e.source` parameter to this page so it can also send message to `index.html`. Since I do not know how the `e` parameter of the `receiveMessage(e)` function passed I am stuck.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [postMessage Source IFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329710/postmessage-source-iframe)